# Scroll-up UITextView when keyboard appears on ios9

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uitextview, ios9

I am trying to scroll-up elements (UIImage and UITextView) embedded in a UIScrollView when the keyboard appears.

My view has the following elements:

```
class EditProfileViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activeTextView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
```

When the view did load I register the delegate and set the keyboard observers:

```
self.textView.delegate = self

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWasShown:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillBeHidden:", name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
```

The methods are the following (wrote thanks to Apple doc):

```
func  textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    self.activeTextView = textView
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    self.activeTextView = nil
}

func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification){
    var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue.size
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, (keyboardSize.height), 0.0)
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    var aRect = self.view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= (keyboardSize.height)
    //if ( !CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.activeTextView.frame.origin)) {
        self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(self.activeTextView.frame, animated: true)
    //}
}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification) {
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}
```

But **nothing** happens when I tap my UITextView to make the keyboard appear. Nothing is scrolled-up, so the keyboard masks my UITextView.

What is wrong in my code?

Thank you for your feedbacks.

Thomas

Comment: Can you confirm that the `keyboardWasShown` actually triggers? Print a message of some sort `print("Keyboard was shown")`..

Comment: Adding to @Laffen's comment, check to see if `keyboardWasShown` is called **after** `textViewDidBeginEditing`. There might be something wrong with `activeTextView`, as you don't do any force unwrapping. Is `activeTextView` implicitly unwrapped?

Comment: Yes, textViewDidBeginEditing is called and then keyboardWasShown is.

Comment: Is the code within your if-statement reached?

Comment: Actually something happens. When the keyboards appears, the view is scroll-up but just a little bit, and then I can manually scroll-up to see the UITextView. I would prefer a big auto scroll-up when the keyboard appears.

Comment: Could you try the following: `let scrollToFrame = CGRect(point: CGPoint(x: frame.minX, y: frame.maxY), size: frame.size)

self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(scrollToFrame, animated: true)` ?

Comment: How do you declare frame and point?

Comment: @Laffen I tried this:
    `let scrollToFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: aRect.minX, y: aRect.maxY), size: aRect.size)
    self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(scrollToFrame, animated: true)`
But same result :(

Comment: Maybe you are reaching the bottom of your `UIScrollView` and therefore unable to scroll any further down ? You could try to set the `contentSize.height + keyboardSize.height` before attempting to scroll, and reset the `contentSize` back to what it was before after keyboard disappears.

Comment: @Laffen Do you mean `self.scrollView.contentSize.height += keyboardSize.height`?

Comment: Yes.. did you try it?

Comment: @Laffen: I corrected my storyboard. Now, when the keyboard appears, the code flow never enters the `if ( !CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.activeTextView.frame.origin))`. If I comment the if, that works great. Any idea?
I edited my code above with the last version.

Comment: So you're saying that the scrolling works as expected when you remove the if-condition?

Comment: @Laffen: Yes that's it